# Multiple GPUImageView displayed in black on iPad 3

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I split a big image into small ones to display with GPUImagePicture/GPUImageView as below.
It works fine for images as big as 3696x2448 (~9M pixels) on iPhone5s, iPad2, iPod touch 5.
And it fails on iPad 3: about a third of small images at the bottom of big image appear in black. Small images are 512x512 in size - I need it in this small size for fast enough processing in later phase.

If I increase the size of small images to 1024x1024, then it works fine (no black output).
However, with this bigger (1024x1024) size, the app becomes very laggy on iPod touch 5.
- All images displayed correctly the first time [picture processImage]; is called. Bug when I tried to adjust brightness.

[Output from my app. Red rectangles represent small images]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcY4T.png
(I don't have enough reputation to post image).

Setup filters:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [imageArray count]; i++)
{
    UIImage *img = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);

    GPUImagePicture *picture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [_sourcePicArray addObject:picture];

    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *filter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
    [_filterArray addObject:filter];
    [picture addTarget:filter];

    GPUImageView *gpuVw = [[GPUImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [imageArray addObject:gpuVw];
    [filter addTarget:gpuVw];

    [picture processImage];
    [picture release];
    [filter release];
}

// Brightness adjust
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [_filterArray count]; i++) {
    GPUImagePicture *picture = [_sourcePicArray objectAtIndex:i];
    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *filter = [_filterArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [filter setBrightness:radius];
    [picture processImage];
}
```

How can I get rid of this annoying black output?